# javascript attaching events

Tags: javascript, events, handler

I've seen that you can attach events like this

```
<button type="button" id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">
```

can you do the same without the `"onclick="`, like:

```
document.getElementById('myButton'). //and here attach the event on click to myFunction
```

I'm trying to keep JavaScript and HTML separate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's similar to the `onclick` approach, and in fact uses the same event-handler, but is removed from the HTML:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function(){
    // do stuff
    myFunction();
}
```

If you don't have an `id` on the element you could also use:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0, len=inputs.length; i<len; i++){
    if (inputs[i].type == 'text'){
        // assuming you want to affect text-inputs in this case
        inputs[i].onclick = function(){
            // do stuff. In here 'this' refers to inputs[i] element
            myFunction();
        };
    }
}
```

An alternative approach, using `Array.prototype.forEach()`, with an array of elements created using `Array.prototype.slice()` and `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelector('input[type="text"]', yourFunctionName);
```

This will execute the `yourFunctionName()` function for each `<input />` element, of `type="text"`, returned by `document.querySelectorAll()` passing that `<input />` element into the function as `this`.

You could also use `addEventListener()` in this case:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

And also in this situation, using `document.querySelector()` (as opposed to `document.querySelectorAll()`), which returns the first element that matches the passed-in selector, using CSS notation:

```
// gets the element with an 'id' of 'myButton', binding the 'click' event-handler:
document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

Or:

```
// gets the first of the <input> elements, binding the 'click' event-handler:
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can (and should!).

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you only need to select your item and call it's correspondant callback function. p.e:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function(e) {
    // your code here
}
```

Or, without the inline function:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = myObject.myMethod;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick

Comment: +1 for avoiding the ever-prevalent inline function — they really are not the panacea so often claimed of them.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
  document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';return false;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {
        console.log('Inline event attach');
    };

    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('Using native addEventListener');
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() { myFunction(); }
```

Comment: You are giving `onclick` the return value of `myFunction()`, unless `myFunction()` returns a function, this is not correct

Comment: You can actually just omit the `()` see Anthony Grist's answer

Comment: thank you @NiftyDude and Anthony Grist, learned something new