# Anchor tag onclick using unobtrusive javascript

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

```
<li id="Account_Tab" class="bgrad">
<a class="bganch" title="Accounts Tab" href="/xxx/xxx">Accounts</a>
</li>
```

there are few other `<li>` tags in the similar way , How can i create an onclick function for the anchor tag,

not like: `<a onclick="function()"......>` is there any other approach other than inline Javascript?

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: do other lis have the anchor elements too

Comment: no jquery , only javascript needed

Comment: Google is your friend (and so is MDN): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: other `<li>` has also the anchor tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript attaching events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335343/javascript-attaching-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the handler like so:

```
function anchorClicked(){
    console.log("clicked");
}

window.onload = function(){
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('bganch');

    for(var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
        anchors[i].onclick = anchorClicked;
    }
};
```

The above adds the click event to elements with the `bganch` class.

Other options:

- Give the anchor an ID and use `document.getElementById('someid')`
- Get all anchors by the tag name using `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`

Comment: how can i get the `title` by using the ` document.getElementsByTagName('a')`

Comment: Use `anchors[i].getAttribute("title")` and change `getElementsByClassName` to `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: wonderful, thanks for the answer , even though it says i have to wait for 6 minutes to accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
window.onload = function(){
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('bganch');

   var anchortitle= anchors.title;
};
```