# how to I make a prompt pop up after a button is hit?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I've tried everything and I'm stuck.  Can someone look at my code and see what I'm missing? I'm making a 'rock, paper, scissors' game.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spock?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.16) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.36) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} 

else if(computerChoice <= 0.56){
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

else if(computerChoice <= 0.76){
    computerChoice = "lizard";
}
else {
    computerChoice = "spock";
}



var compare = function(userChoice, computerChoice) {
   if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
       return"It's a tie!"}
```

I have an html doc attached to the js file.  I want to make `userChoice` appear after a button is pressed.

Comment: Attach an event listener to the button

Comment: I imagine there are tons of answers to this already on stack overflow. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335343/javascript-attaching-events